# How to pass parameters to click event method using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

i have this button on my C# context:

```
<button id='Update' OnServerClick='UpdateCart'>Update</button>
```

now I wanna to pass parameter (num) to  (UpdateCart) Method :

```
protected void UpdateCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Cookies["Cart"]["Qty(" + num + ")"] = Request.Form["Qty" + num];
}
```

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 6):

Use ASP.NET [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) control instead of `<button/>` markup that allow you to  set value via  CommandArgument property and use Command event (do not use Click) to retrieve value of `CommandArgument` property.

Markup:

```
 <asp:Button 
              ID="Button1" 
              runat="server" 
              CommandArgument="10" 
              oncommand="Button1_Command" 
              Text="Button" />
```

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
  {
      string value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: I Do all that but still cannot access the value (e.CommandArgument) it is empty

Comment: @Hatem - Yes! I think there is something missing. You have to update your post and add working code in it.

Answer (score 4):

You would use the 'commandArgument' attribute.  Here's an example on the MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx

Comment: I Do all that but still cannot access the value (e.CommandArgument) it is null

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that command argument does not accept dynamically set values from client side, command argument must be set server side. So to combat this I used `asp:hidden` field updated its `value` and then from code behind got the value by just doing `hiddenfield.value`.